Best way to store unique id's for one time links
I am currently working on company shop build just for the bigger grocery stores to buy products from us, and i need to add a function for them to logIn without a password
Now come the difficult part
The ide is that we add all the email for the the companys manually in the database and then every time they enter email on the main page they get a one time link with unique id that they can use to buy items.
The project need to be build with nextJS 14, i am past react developer so i would usually just use useParams for uniqe id and routing. But now i don't know how to do.
Should i save the unique id that generets and send with email in the database and delete it after some time or is there any better way to make so id is just active around 1 day

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
